# React Native code stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am dealing with a very strange problem. My React Native code was working fine till yesterday. I was trying to import FB data (User ID, Profile Pic etc) and was successfully able to see the FB User ID on my app till yesterday. All of a sudden I can't see it anymore..

I get the following log when I use expo start and just a blank screen on my phone.
I have tried clearing cache and updating expo-cli as well.. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

```
Running application on Redmi 6 Pro.

Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See 

fb.me/react-unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
* Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: %s, Login
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:117:10 in registerWarning
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:63:8 in warnImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:36:4 in console.warn
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:18:4 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:106:4 in printWarning
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:60:16 in warn
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5846:10 in ReactStrictModeWarnings.flushPendingUnsafeLifecycleWarnings
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19093:6 in flushRenderPhaseStrictModeWarningsInDEV      
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18335:41 in commitRootImpl
* [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
- node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18317:17 in commitRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17697:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
* [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20527:14 in updateContainer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21068:17 in render
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:54:4 in renderApplication
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:213:4 in runApplication
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Best,
Nitin

Comment: Did you follow all of the recommendations in that output? It's pretty clear what you need to do from that output

Comment: `componentWillMount` for all practical purposes is deprecated, and has been for a year, year and a half (v16.3.0). https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes. React even provided a script to help automate the update: https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod#rename-unsafe-lifecycles.

Comment: I agree that I've been ignoring warnings but the code was working fine till yesterday. I could see the output on my phone.. I will update though and see if that works..

Comment: delete node modules folder then run npm install and try.

Comment: It is *just* a warning, not an error, so it will likely *still* work (for the time being), but given React has been warning devs to update for well over a year and the warnings have progressively strengthened, well... they have to draw a line at some point. May as well just update and use the more correct lifecycle methods anyway.

Comment: Tried deleting node modules folder and ran npm install but the problem persists.